# how to create a data bag as part of chef script

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, knife

I need to create a data bag and then an data bag item **USING CHEF RECIPE**. I an unable to do so.
I have the content also ready which is as follows

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'chef/encrypted_data_bag_item'

secret = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load_secret('/root/data_bag')
data = {"id" => "TEST", "root" => "root", "passwd" => "passwd"}
encrypted_data = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.encrypt_data_bag_item(data, secret)
```

Now that i have the content , i need to create a data bag and an item , and then append the content in to that item . this is the approach which i tried for creating a data bag. But it failed.

```
new_databag = Chef::DataBag.new
new_databag.name('list')
new_databag.save
```

when i am using `new_databag.save` its saying forbidden.

Below is the snippet for creating the data bag item,which i got it over the internet. but how do we specify the item name which we want to give.

```
item = Chef::DataBagItem.new
item.data_bag('list')
item.raw_data = data
item.save
```

Any help would be appreciated ..!!

Comment: What versions of Chef Server and chef-client are you using?

Comment: @JavierCortejoso  i tried in 11.x and 12.x versions

Comment: any leads @JavierCortejoso ..??

Comment: There were a bug in old versions of Chef that may be related, but if you are using latest version it should be solved: https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-4435

Answer (score 2):

Chef clients do not have *permission to create/update data bags* (holds true for other containers such as roles).

If you see a "403 Forbidden" change permissions for clients under "Administration > Global Permissions > data_bags" in chef server. 
To use knife you would have to install the "knife-acl" plugin.

This operation will not change permissions for *existing* data bags though!

Comment: Is there any documetnation on that, or examples of how to allow chef-client's the ability to do that?